# datepicker resetting the value

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am trying to perform the following actions on the datepicker:

1) click on the input field of the datepciker and navigate to the next month (say March)
2) I do not do any selection but close the datepicker.
3) I come back to the datepicker field and i still see the datepiker in March

Is there a way to reset the display back to February(current month)?

I am using the following code on ng-focus for the input field, but it doesn't seem to work:

View:

```
<input class="inputFilterMinTemp" id = "st_date" type="text" ng-    model="name.StartDate" ng-focus = "resetCal()" placeholder="Search"  />
```

Controller:

```
$scope.resetCal = function()
{
$('#st_date').datepicker("setDate",null);
};

$scope.init = function()
{
           $('#st_date').datepicker({
                    format: "dd-M-yyyy",
                    autoclose: true
                }).on('changeDate', function(e) {

                });
};
```

Any idea how i can do this?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: can you put a demonstration? when you edit your question use `<>` code icon to reproduce that in snippet.

Comment: @Raviteja added the code

Comment: see my ans hope its helpfull

Comment: Any link to the datepicker you are using ?

Comment: @Raviteja heres the link //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js

Comment: Could you make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
  $('#st_date').on('hide', function(){       

            if($('#st_date').val() == "")
            {
            $('#st_date').datepicker('setDate',null);
            }
}).datepicker();
```

If no selection has been made, reset back to the current month on click of the date picker again

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $("#end_date").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        "setDate": currentDate
    })
```